# How to avoid duplicate dependencies in play module based projects

Tags: playframework, architecture, java-8, sbt

In my play project, I separated the big parts in multiple modules. Now, each module has its own build.sbt file and mentioned dependencies inside it. During each compilation time there are several common sbt dependencies be downloaded for each project. I want to mention the common dependencies in a single sbt project from where each and every independent modules receive their dependent target.

### #

```
---main module---
 |             |
sub-module1   sub-module2
   |             |
[how to have ?] common sbt container
```

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is described in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects#Sharing-common-variables-and-code.

Comment: [Example of multiproject template](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-multidomain-auth)